# Magento Custom Menu Admin not visible for User but visible for Administrators

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, user-roles, acl, adminmenu

I have a module that updates the amin menu by inserting a submenu called "Relatórios Personalizados" in the reports menu.

I set the role permissions for the user named "Luciano", however the menu is not visible to him.

But when I'm as admin, the menu is visible.

**The role definition**
[image: The role definition]

**The user definition**
[image]

**Logged as user**
[image]

**Logged as admin**
[image]

**My folder structure**

[image]

**In my controller**

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return true;
}
```

**My adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
    <report>
        <children>
            <customreport translate="title" module="vitali_customreport">
                <title>Relatorios Personalizados</title>
                <sort_order>5000</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <sales module="vitali_customreport" translate="title">
                        <title>Vendas</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/customreport/sales</action>
                    </sales>
                    <salesbyattrset module="vitali_customreport" translate="title">
                        <title>Vendas por Tipo de Produto</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/customreport/salesbyattrset</action>
                    </salesbyattrset>
                    <productsold module="vitali_customreport" translate="title">
                        <title>Produtos Comprados</title>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/customreport/productsold</action>
                    </productsold>
                    <treatment module="vitali_customreport" translate="title">
                        <title>Tempo de Tratamento</title>
                        <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/customreport/treatment</action>
                    </treatment>
                </children>
            </customreport>
        </children>
    </report>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <customreport translate="title" module="vitali_customreport">
                    <title>Relatórios Personalizados</title>
                    <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <sales translate="title" module="vitali_customreport">
                            <title>Vendas</title>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        </sales>
                        <salesbyattrset translate="title" module="vitali_customreport">
                            <title>Vendas por Tipo de Produto</title>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        </salesbyattrset>
                        <productsold translate="title" module="vitali_customreport">
                            <title>Produtos Comprados</title>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        </productsold>
                        <treatment translate="title" module="vitali_customreport">
                            <title>Tempo de Tratamento</title>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                        </treatment>
                    </children>
                </customreport>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Comment: did luciano log out and log in again?

Comment: @Marius yes, I logged in anonimous tab chrome after clear all caches in magento.

Comment: @Marius I found the solution following the idea suggested by QaisarSatti that the error was in the ACL block xml. Thanks for your attemption, and I posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answer, I found the solution, the problem was that the **ACL** did **not contain** the part of the **reports** session, so I updated the xml to contain this information:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <!-- start fix-->
                <report>
                    <children>
                    ...
                    </children>
                </report>
                <!-- end fix-->
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<sort_order>-100</sort_order>` mismatched `<sort_order>5000</sort_order>`

also action missing in **acl**

```
<action>adminhtml/customreport/treatment</action>
```

replace **acl** with

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <customreport translate="title" module="vitali_customreport">
                <title>Relatorios Personalizados</title>
                <sort_order>5000</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <sales module="vitali_customreport" translate="title">
                        <title>Vendas</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/customreport/sales</action>
                    </sales>
                    <salesbyattrset module="vitali_customreport" translate="title">
                        <title>Vendas por Tipo de Produto</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/customreport/salesbyattrset</action>
                    </salesbyattrset>
                    <productsold module="vitali_customreport" translate="title">
                        <title>Produtos Comprados</title>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/customreport/productsold</action>
                    </productsold>
                    <treatment module="vitali_customreport" translate="title">
                        <title>Tempo de Tratamento</title>
                        <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/customreport/treatment</action>
                    </treatment>
                </children>
              </customreport>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Comment: sort order has nothing to do with it and the acl section should not contain actions. take a look at this for example: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/adminhtml.xml

Comment: @Qaisar Satti Thanks for yor answer, I have modified the xml like your suggestion, but still not working

Comment: @Marius i faced the problem one time it solved for me

Comment: @QaisarSatti I found the solution following the idea that the error was in the ACL block xml. Thanks for your attemption, and I posted the answer